# Weld CDI does not log exceptions unless debug level is switched on

Tags: cdi, weld, jboss-weld

We have noticed that if an exception is thrown while CDI events are being processed - for example with `@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMPLETION)` - then the exception is not logged if the log level is above `DEBUG`.

Weld logs something simple like this:

```
16:31:41,732 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Event] WELD-000401 Failure while notifying an observer of event SomeEventDTO
```

Lines 85-86 of the `DeferredEventNotification` from Weld show the problem: https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/modules/jta/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/module/jta/DeferredEventNotification.java

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        EventLogger.LOG.asyncObserverFailure(metadata);
        EventLogger.LOG.catchingDebug(e);
    }
```

Is this because the specs say the exception and its stacktrace don't need to be logged, or is this because Weld is rather (too) relaxed in its handling of exceptions.

Is there a better solution than wrapping all event observing code with a try-catch block?

Note: setting the standard Log Level for `org.jboss.weld.Event` to `DEBUG` causes a little too much logging. Each sent event is also logged:

```
17:47:14,088 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Event] WELD-000400 Sending event SomeEventDTO directly to observer [method] public com.foo.bar.BeanClass.methodName(SomeEventDTO)
```

Comment: Your own first console log shows that the level of logging for WELD-000401 is actually `ERROR`. Therefore it does not make sense to be only visible with `DEBUG` level. I would first make sure you have logging set correctly in your AS. For instance with WildFly you need to set separately the level for Weld and for WildFly console itself.

Comment: @Siliarus I don't understand what you mean. If I set logging generally to ERROR, I only get the line with WELD-000401 and NO stacktrace.  If I set the logging level generally to DEBUG, I also get the stacktrace. That means Weld is effectively hiding the exception in a Production environment where the log level will not be DEBUG. How am I supposed to know what the actual error is, if Weld is only logging it at DEBUG level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your question (sorry for the confusion before), let me shed some light.

The error message seems to be intentionally hidden by Weld. There are no specification restraints on logging whatsoever. As far as exceptions are concerned, the specification merely describes what should blow up and when.

Also, you are using Weld JTA module which I think does not correspond to any CDI spec part (meaning its Weld-specific) so it might not have a say there anyway.

**Now to the solution**, I think you have a fair point with the logging, it doesn't really help. Therefore, I went ahead and created a [JIRA issue (WELD-2330)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2330). Since this is 3.x branch, it should be fixed pretty quickly. Feel free to jump in and have a say in it or even contribute.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I just have to wait for a) JBoss to use the latest version of Weld and b) the customer to upgrade to that JBoss version. Hopefully that will all happen before Easter, when we go live... :-)

Comment: As a work around until then, I guess we could turn on DEBUG logging for Weld events and use a logging filter to turn off the stuff that we don't want, à la http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2421

Comment: Hmm, the code you pointed to is on master branch (Weld 3.0/CDI 2.0) and in the issue there is also a fix for 2.4 Weld (which is in EAP 6.x/7.x and Wildfly). However, if you are using JBoss AS 7, this won't help you; that's Weld 1.x which isn't actively developed anymore. In that case would be only left with the filtering of debug log I am afraid. Is that the case?

Comment: Uh, small mistake in the comment above, Weld 2.4 is in EAP 7.x (*not* in EAP 6)

Comment: I think we will go with filtering in the short term. Thanks again for your help, it is very much appreciated!